# SQL Server 2008: how to add logins to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, logging

I'm dbowner on certain database (my account is on public role on server login but dbowner role on certain databases). Now when I try to add logins from server logins, I can only see sa account and my account. How can I add user to my databases from server logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need administrator rights to be able to add users to your database. You should be able to add users if you have the "sysadmin" server role checked on your account properties.

There's a fuller description of the various roles [here](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Roles.htm). This is relevant:

> The members of **securityadmin** server role can create and manage server logins and auditing, and read error logs.

So if you can't add the "sysadmin" role, can you add the "securityadmin" role to the account?

Comment: Thanks, but we would like to keep sysadmins separated from dbowners, so that dbowner could add users to their databases. Sysadmin does neccesarily know which users to add to these databases.

Comment: @jrara - I've updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: It seems that my must use SecurityAdmin Server Role for those who want add users to databases.